# can't get old() to work in laravel

Tags: laravel

in my blade i have 2 radio inputs

```
<form class="" action="{{route('admin.album.search')}}" method="post">
<input id="slug" type="radio" name="search" value="slug" >
<input id="id" type="radio" name="search" value="id">
```

in the same blade file I test to see old value of radio input

```
{{ old('search')}}
```

When I select first radio button and submit the form and page reloads I expect that old will be selected radio button value but nothing comes out. What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<form class="" action="{{route('admin.album.search')}}" method="post">
{{ csrf_field() }}
<input id="slug" 
    type="radio" 
    name="search" 
    value="slug" 
    {{ (old('search') == 'slug') ? 'checked': '' }}>

<input id="id" 
    type="radio" 
    name="search" 
    value="id" 
    {{ (old('search') == 'id') ? 'checked': '' }}>
```

**N.T.** If you submit post form request you must be specify `csrf_field()`. Otherwise it gives you `token` mismatch exception.

Comment: Hi i did try that as well and nothing gets checked, it's weird

Comment: When you redirect from controller please make sure you redirect `->withInput()`. If you not than `old('search')` not been exists.